# Adobe AIR: How do I get the current endpoint URI?

Tags: air, flex4.5, graniteds

I need to open a HTTP link to the webserver which my air app is talking to but I don't want to hard-code the webserver URL into the Flex code. If I can get the endpoint URI then I can work from there. I'm using GraniteDS in case that is relevant.

Comment: I've had the same question myself (never posted a question though) and haven't really found anything. I've tried digging into the connection, but the url isn't there. I hope you can find an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import mx.messaging.config.ServerConfig;

ServerConfig.getChannel(CHANNEL_ID).uri;

Comment: Sweet! That worked perfectly, good find! :) I couldn't find that class in the api document, where did you find this out?

Comment: Franck Wolff - graniteDS mailing list